# iOS Autolayout not working for iphone 6

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, autolayout, uistoryboard

I'm having real trouble here for some time. I'm not using size classes (app is for os 6 +). I'm using auto layout, I don't want to have multiple storyboards for each screen size. For 3.5 and 4 inch screen everything is ok. For 4.7 + inch it's not. So to show you what is the problem. This is for 3.5 and 4 inch screen:

[image]

This is 4.7 inch screen:

[image]

As you see, right arrow goes to the left. It has Vertical Center in container and its height is 28x28. It has right constraint 8 points like this (I've unchecked Constrains to margin):

[image]

I cannot make it work for iPhone 6 and iPhone 6 plus. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: check that your superview pinned to edges or not

Comment: change the superview's background color and check

Comment: Post your constraint of the Label